# Python script on cron

Tags: python, cron

I like to execute a python script from cron every minute.

I was wondering: this script is gonna send some files via samba to a shared folder. If the process took more than one minute, the next time cron raises the script, would it execute it?

Because the previous script was still being executing.

If this run in this way, I would have to put something to not run the process. For example I had thought in write some file and before executing, read it.

Comment: Why dont you make an infinite loop within the script, and set some kind of clock or time wait, before it loops again? Then you would only need to run the script at startup

Answer (score 2):

Cron doesn't check whether a previous instance was running or not, for all it knows, it simply checks the time against the conditions. You'll have to put a check in the script to prevent multiple parallel execution.

Comment: Thanks very much, what I thought. I will try it. What do you think about the way I said? Is there any better way? Or smarter.

Comment: @ars1614 use [`fcntl.flock`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.flock) to lock a   file. That's probably the safest way to prevent multiple execution.

Comment: @ars1614 almost certainly, but we can't know since you haven't given us any details about what you're trying to do. From what little you say, I would guess the best solution for you would be to use [`inotify`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man7/inotify.7.html). I suggest you ask a new question and explain your situation in more detail.

Comment: Ok thanks you two. I will search for those two options and if I do not find any solution I will post again.

Comment: I agree with terdon, polling probably isn't the best thing you can do, so use inotify or, because you are already using Python, use Watchdog: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog.

Comment: @SamuelSantana flock isn't polling. It, depending on the arguments, either blocks until the lock is available or fails. The failure option can be used for polling, but that's not the only use.

Comment: I was referring to his current/previous approach, that seems like polling to me.

Comment: @SamuelSantana in that case, you should ping the user, since without `@ars1614`, only I get notified and the comment seems to be a response to me.

Comment: On second thought, setting a cron job isn't really polling, is it? I mean, cron itself is polling, but that already happens, whether he adds a job or not. So your proposed solution now seems better, because he won't have to fiddle with inotify or python's watchdog.